# how to check if password contain at least 1 numeric digit in Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio

I am a beginner in programming. We use VISUAL BASIC language

1) the password should be at least 6 characters long
2) the password should contain at least one numeric digit and at least one alphabetic character. HOW CAN I CHECK IF PASSWORD CONTAINS AT LEAST 1 NUMERIC DIGIT? I wrote this code:

```
Function IsValid(input As String) As Boolean
    input = input.Trim()

    If input.Length < 6 OrElse IsNumeric(input) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Your password should be at least 6 characters long,
        contain at least one numeric digit and at least one alphabetic character")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    If IsValid(txtInput.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for creating your new password.")
    End If
End Sub
```

HOW CAN I CHECK IF PASSWORD CONTAINS AT LEAST 1 NUMERIC DIGIT?
Thanks

Comment: Check out Regex (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use "\d" pattern, to match for digits.

Comment: is there another way to do it? the easier one? because we didn't study REGEX yet and teacher said to do it in a simpler way.

Comment: Then I suggest you loop through the string and check every character, until you find a number, or return an error if you didn't find a number after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one boolean method ValidatePassword as sown below and pass password entered. To validate numbers function will use regular expression. As you will be checking for only minimum length, one alphabetic char and one numeric digit we will use two regular expressions as ['a-z','A-Z'] for alphabets and ['0-9'] for numbers.

```
Function ValidatePassword(ByVal pwd As String, Optional ByVal minLength As Integer = 6, Optional ByVal numNumbers As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal numAlphabet As Integer = 1) As Boolean
    Dim number As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]")
    Dim alphabet As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[A-Z],[a-z]")
    ' Check the length.
    If Len(pwd) < minLength Then Return False
    ' Check for minimum number of occurrences.
    If number.Matches(pwd).Count < numNumbers Then Return False
    ' Check for minimum number of occurrences.
    If alphabet.Matches(pwd).Count < numLower Then Return False
    ' Passed all checks.
    Return True
End Function
```

Get the complete checking for Complex password here http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/6828/vbnet-password-complexity.html